# How to remove quotes/double quotes from $_POST[] item?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to remove quotes and double quotes from a post return, but nothing worked, for example:

I have a HTML form using a POST method, inside I have a text input named 'txtDescription':

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtDescription" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If the user inserts:

> my name is 'Luis'

I want to remove the quotes on the PHP part, here's what I've tried:

```
$text = $_POST["txtDescription"];
$newText = str_replace("'", "", $text);
echo $newText;
```

But it doesn't remove the quotes, if I make like below:

```
$text = "my name is 'Luis'";
$newText = str_replace("'", "", $text);
echo $newText;
```

Then it works, but why? And how to remove it?

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST["txtDescription"]` contains `"my name is 'Luis'"` ? Please try to `var_dump($_POST)` and check

Comment: Oh, it was converting to &quot;, now I can fix it. Thanks xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this may help you to remove `&quot;`

```
$str = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","", $str);
```